# Adding a list of points together

Tags: list, haskell

How do I  add all of the  `x` coordinates together in a list of points type `Pt`?

Example:

```
 [Pt 1 2, Pt 3 4]  =>  1 + 3  =>  4
```

Here is the data-type and function declaration that I am using:

```
data Point = Pt Double Double

x :: [Point] -> Point
```

This is what I have tried.

```
x :: [Point] -> Point
x  [Pt x y] = Pt(x+x)
```

Comment: Your signature suggests that this would be a `Point` as result, so something like `(4,6)`?

Comment: Furthermore what did you try? What is not working?

Comment: I am just having a hard time trying to understand how to work with this because I know to work with a list you use (x:xs), but I do not understand how to work with this list.

Comment: not per se, you can use functions like `map`, `foldr`, etc. as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this, is by first making a function that can extract the *x*-coordinate of a point. For example with `xPt`:

```
xPt :: Point -> Double
xPt (Pt x _) = x
```

then we can make use of [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) and [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to map a list of points to a list of *x*-coordinates:

```
xSum :: [Point] -> Double
xSum = sum . map xPt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
xSum :: [Point] -> Double
xSum pts = sum [x | Pt x _ <- pts]
```